# Visual Studio stack trace in notepad++

Tags: visual-studio, notepad++

This is probably just a setting I'm not seeing, but when I get a stack trace out of Visual Studio's exception helper dialog, it has \r\n after each "line" in the call stack. When I copy this and paste it into Notepad++, it shows up as literally \r\n, visible in the document. Of course I'd like these to be interpreted as CR LF, so everything's on a different line.

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Why not just replace (in Notepad++) the "\r\n" with any character that does not occur in your text and then replace the character with "\r\n" (this time with the setting "Extended search mode" in the Replace dialog?

Comment: that totally worked. you should answer the question though, because I can't mark a comment as the answer. Unless someone can find a menu command that will do this :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this question is old, but maybe someone will find the solution helpful.

Open `find and replace`, and
go to the replace tab

In the find box type `\\r\\n`

In the replace box type `\r\n` (both without quotes)

Make sure the `Extended search mode` is selected in the bottom left.

Finally, hit replace all.

[image: Screenshot of my window].

Answer (score 1):

It took me a while the first time to find the setting. It's View >> Show Symbol >> Show All Characters. [image]

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a Notepad++ bug.  I can paste into regular Notepad and UltraEdit without the side effects you describe.

Like Cerebrus says, you can workaround it on the Notepad++ side by using its search/replace facility.